# Android: App/broadcast receiver is getting killed sometimes when I receive an incoming call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have written an interceptor to access a call data when there is an incoming call. I listen to state change action to decide whether it is a missed call or received call. I have written a code to do things whenever call **ends**.

```
public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  public static final String TAG = "PHONE STATE";
  private static String mLastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE); 

    if (!state.equals(mLastState)) {
      mLastState = state;
      Log.e(TAG, state);  
      return;
    }
    //Code to do stuff based on last state and state
  }  
}
```

The code works fine. But I noticed my app failed to process some of the calls. As this issue was hard to reproduce, I monitored my app for a whole day based on my call activity. When I debugged the issue, I found out that `mLastState` wasn't changing in such cases. It was still `IDLE` in case when incoming call ends where it should have been `RINGING` or `OFFHOOK`. The reason for that was my app was getting killed and `mLastState` was being reinitialized. So I was losing the last state.

How to handle this situation? First solution came to my mind was to persist a `mLastState` to a sharedpreference. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: In my opinion adding the 6 lilnes of code needed to load/save via sharedpreference is the easiest solution.

Comment: @k3b : or would initializing `mLastState` to -1 be fine?

Comment: Please, post the AndroidManifest as well, for us to see what is triggering your BroadcastReceiver.